# Vaadin push: Push is not available

Tags: push, vaadin

I have a Maven project, I added vaadin-push as dependency in the pom.xml.

The first problem is in the MainUI class, when I add the annotation `@Push(PushMode.MANUAL)` it doesn't recognize the `PushMode` so I am stuck with `@Push`. When I add it, i get the error message when I access the UI:

```
{"timestamp":1519112562626,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.vaadin.server.ServiceException","message":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Push is not available. See previous log messages for more information.","path":"/bp/list"}
```

I tried to follow the instructions on [vaadin website on push](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html) so I added a web.xml (I didnt have one previously). I'm not sure whether it is being used. I would prefer to configure this solely by annotations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Business Process UI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>UI</param-name>
        <param-value>com.oursys.bpspkpibpcheck.view.MainUI</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- Enable server push -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>pushmode</param-name>
      <param-value>automatic</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </servlet>
</web-app>
```

What I actually want to achieve is to update the UI on a Rest request, I think the Rest part already works apart from the Push:

```
public class UILister {

    private static HashMap<UUID,MainUI> uiByUuid = new HashMap<UUID,MainUI>();

    public static void closeUIConnectorFrame(UUID uuid) {
        MainUI ui = uiByUuid.get(uuid);
        if(ui != null) {
            ui.access(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ui.closeConnectorFrame();
                    ui.push();
                }}
            );
        }
    }

    public static void addUI(UUID uuid, MainUI mainUI) {
        uiByUuid.put(uuid, mainUI);
    }
}
```

pom.xml. I removed the vaadin-push since it tells me I am overriding the one configured automatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.leosoftsys</groupId>
    <artifactId>bpsp-kpi-bp-check</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>bpsp-kpi-bp-check</name>
    <description>Business Check For BPS+</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.1.1</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-docs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>confirmdialog</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-sass-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
            <artifactId>failsafe</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>failsafe-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
           </resource>
           <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Please show you pom.xml, since there seems to be the problem and not in your code.

Comment: Added pom.xml to question

Comment: `vaadin-push`is commented out in your pom.xml

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the pom.xml, the error message goes away when I comment in the `vaadin-push`. Now I just have to check whether the UI.push works.

Comment: I still can't set the PushMode, it says variable not found. In `@Push(PushMode.MANUAL)`. And I get various errors now which I didn't get without the push

Comment: Strange now eclipse found the PushMode didn't change anything.

Comment: The IDE usually cache many things and annotation handling is always a little "freaky" ;)

Comment: I'm using `@Push(value=PushMode.MANUAL, transport=Transport.LONG_POLLING)` now it avoids the no-cookies problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pom, add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

You don't need to specify a `<version>` here, since the version is *managed* by `vaadin-bom` (bill of materials) which declares the correct version for each artifact (so that it is easier to avoid conflicting dependencies to different versions of the same framework), but importing the BOM doesn't add the dependencies by itself.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

> I removed the vaadin-push since it tells me I am overriding the one configured automatically.

The *one configured automatically* refers to the version *managed* by the BOM. For instance, when one adds a dependency to `vaadin-push` with a `<version>` tag, Eclipse it gives the following warning:

> Overriding managed version 8.1.1 for vaadin-push